How can I raise a subfloor 1-1/4"?
Our two story house is built in 1998. For some weird reason part of the second floor is built 1 1/4 lower than the rest of the floor. In the hallway at some point floor goes down and then it is flat in both bedrooms.
Floor slope starts at about green line and at about blue line it is already lower 1 1/4 inch. From that point on to the exterior wall floor is flat and level.
We want to lay laminate on the 2nd story from wall to wall without any transitions. For that purpose we need to raise the subfloor once we remove the carpet and padding.
There are few way on how this can be done:
Option 1: Strips of 15/32 plywood perpendicular to existing joists, screwed in into joists and covered with 23/32 OSB subfloor
Option 2: sandwich of 2x glued together 19/32 OSB laid perpendicular to existing subfloor
What is the better option?
Any nuances I should keep in mind as far as fasteners/glue?
Thanks


Plywood is stronger and will handle moisture better than OSB which becomes sawdust

OSB does not become sawdust (and it doesn't contain sawdust). It's built with exterior-grade adhesive, just like plywood. It does swell a bit more, but only under heavy and prolonged wetting. It's often more stable and flatter than plywood.

Your idea is reasonable, though I'd clarify a couple things:

Consider using 5/8" nominal as the base layer. This addresses the underheight issue mentioned by Michael Karas. However, small variations can be easily remedied by shimming up the transition as needed with custom strips tapered out over say 4 feet. You might mock it up with some scrap to see which size is best.

Run the intermediate strips parallel with the joists. You want to continue that linear support through to the upper subfloor, and not reduce it to points on a grid. OSB has a strength axis you need to respect with full crosswise and edge support. (Also run strips around the perimeter of each area.)

Use wider strips to add rigidity. 3/4" OSB (or plywood) has barely adequate stiffness, in my opinion, and leaves too much bounce in a floor. By using supporting strips of say 6" wide you transmit strength through from the lower subfloor to the upper, improving the overall quality of your floor.

Use glue and screws of adequate length for everything. (If they strip before pulling below flush they're too short.) Don't worry about decoupling layers or any of that. It's not a concern.



"Solid" answer.  Given what I've seen in an old house the plywood would be stronger and better handle more eventualities including water leaks.

Thank you all for your responses. Yes, I understand that I am 1/16 short but in the greater scheme of things it is negligible. Price difference between strips of plywood or osb is not that big than two solid pieces.
When using sandwich of 2 osb's do I put them in the same manner as existing ones, or should I put them perpendicular to existing subfloor?
Should I use PL400 adhesive or Liquid Nails Subfloor and Deck?

As I said, OSB has a strength access that must be respected. It should be oriented perpendicular to the supporting framing. Do try to stagger joints, though. Any heavy duty construction adhesive will be fine.

I am a big proponent of solid floors rather than having strips in between. A good way to install would be to put down each layer of the OSB separately gluing and screwing. This will result in a very rigid floor with minimal possibility for squeaks developing over time.
Both of the thickness recipes that you describe add up to 1.1875" which is not the 1.250" that you said that you need. You would still be short 1/16".

It depends.  A semi-sprung floor is nicer to walk on than a solid floor (concrete).  The 1/16" could easily be made up with a layer or two of plain jane sheet vinyl.
